# Extracting the duration and thumbnail from video

Tags: go, video-streaming, grpc

I'm trying the get the duration and a thumbnail from a byte array which belongs to a video, I'm send the video through gRPC method using client streaming

```
    info := firstMessage.GetInfo()
    if info == nil {
        return errors.Errorf(errors.FirstMessageNotInfo)
    }

    imageSize := 0

    fileBytes := make([]byte, 0)

    writer, fileName, err := i.service.CreateFileWriter(info.Type)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Errorf(errors.UnknownError, err)
    }

    // All the messages except the first one is bytes of data that constitutes a part of the file
    for {
        req, dataErr := stream.Recv()
        if dataErr != nil {
            break
        }

        chunk := req.GetData()
        imageSize += len(chunk)

        fileBytes = append(fileBytes, chunk...)
    }

    if info.GetType() == "video" {
        duration, thumbnail , err := utils.ExtractDurationAndFrameFromVideo(fileBytes)
    }
```

is there's a way to get these details from byte array without saving the video and re-open it using some libs like ffmpeg ?

a way to extract the duration and frames from byte array

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements aren't entirely clear. You're trying to avoid saving it to disk, but you keep a copy of the entire file in ram. Isn't that a more expensive resource?

Also: do you want to avoid ffmpeg, or avoid writing to disk?

I'd recommend streaming the data to ffmpeg's stdin. That'll allow you to avoid both a disk and in-memory copy of the entire video.

If the in-memory copy is not a problem, there's libraries like https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/3d0c/gmf or https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/AlexEidt/Vidio that can call ffmpeg for you.